# How can I solve an Unit Commitment by calling CPLEX with the method of Mix Integer Quadratic Programming

Tags: matlab, cplex

The function in CPLEX can only solve up to a quadratic problem. And if a cost function is quadratic, and it should be multiplied with a commitment vector, then it becomes a third order equation. 
Many papers have explained how to transfer a quadratic function to a stairwise function, and the mathematical way is easy to understand. However I don't know how to put the transferred functions into the cplexmiqp() in Cplex cause the coefficient matrix is hard to determine. 
Could anybody tell me how to implement this question into cplex function and, if possible, a sample program will be of great help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not multiply the cost with the binary variable. Instead you use logical implications to model it.

Instead of writing d*P^2 where d is binary and P is a continuous variable, you introduce a new variable, let us call it B. If d is 0, then B should be zero, otherwise it should be equal to P. Your new objective is B^2. The only thing left is to model the logic

```
d = 0 implies B = 0
d = 1 implies B = P
```

This is typically done using big-M techniques. If you know P is non-negative and limited from above by, say, 100, you can write it as

```
0 <= B <= 100*d
-100*(1-d) <= P-B <= 100*(1-d)
```

The only sample code I can supply is an example in the MATLAB based modelling layer YALMIP which can be used to interface cplex
http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Examples.UnitCommitment